# What is dimension of range(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ denote vector space of polynomials in variable $x$ of degree at most $n$. Let $T$ be linear and $T: P_2\to P_4$ s.t. $x \to x^2$.

Now I think dimension of $range(T)$ is $3$ which will be generated by $1,x^2,x^4$. Am I correct?

Comment: Do you mean $v\mapsto v^2$ for all $v\in P_2$?  If so, you shouldn't use the same symbol, $x$, to refer to this arbitrary element of $P_2$ AND the specific element of the space $P_2 = \operatorname{span}(1,x,x^2)$.  In that case this is not a linear transformation -- it's quadratic.

Comment: Or if you actually do mean that $T$ takes the element $x$ to $x^2$, then $T$ is not completely specified.  So you can't determine the dimension of the range.  You can only say that $1\le \dim(\operatorname{range}(T)) \le 3$.

Comment: Do you mean $T(f(x))=f(x^2)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not completely clear from your problem statement it seems that your map is the linear map $T:P_2\to P_4$ defined by
$$
T\left(a_0+a_1 t+a_2t^2\right)=a_0+a_1t^2+a_2t^4
$$
One way to determine the rank of $T$ is to compute its matrix representation in the standard bases. To do so, note that
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
T(1) & = & \color{red}{1}\cdot 1 & + & \color{red}{0}\cdot t
& + & \color{red}{0}\cdot t^2 & + & \color{red}{0}\cdot t^3
& + & \color{red}{0}\cdot t^4 \\
T(t) & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1 & + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t
& + & \color{blue}{1}\cdot t^2& + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t^3& + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t^4 \\
T(t^2) & = & \color{green}{0}\cdot 1 &+& \color{green}{0}\cdot t 
&+& \color{green}{0}\cdot t^2&+& \color{green}{0}\cdot t^3&+& \color{green}{1}\cdot t^4 
\end{array}
Thus
$$
[T]=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{0}\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{0}\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{green}{0}\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{0}\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix is clearly rank three. Hence $T$ is also rank three.

If we interpret your problem more literally, then the only information we know about $T$ is that $T(t)=t^2$. In this case we have
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
T(1) & = & \color{red}{?}\cdot 1 & + & \color{red}{?}\cdot t
& + & \color{red}{?}\cdot t^2 & + & \color{red}{?}\cdot t^3
& + & \color{red}{?}\cdot t^4 \\
T(t) & = & \color{blue}{0}\cdot 1 & + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t
& + & \color{blue}{1}\cdot t^2& + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t^3& + & \color{blue}{0}\cdot t^4 \\
T(t^2) & = & \color{green}{?}\cdot 1 &+& \color{green}{?}\cdot t 
&+& \color{green}{?}\cdot t^2&+& \color{green}{?}\cdot t^3&+& \color{green}{?}\cdot t^4 
\end{array}
Thus
$$
[T]=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{?} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{?}\\
\color{red}{?} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{?}\\
\color{red}{?} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{green}{?}\\
\color{red}{?} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{?}\\
\color{red}{?} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{green}{?}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix has rank *at least* one, but the rank could be two or three.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $T$ is linear. A basis for $P_2$ is $\{1, x, x^2 \}$, and $T$ is determined by its values on these elements. Knowing $T(x^2) = x^4 \neq 0$ tells you that the dimension of range$(T)$ is $\geq 1$.

Comment: sorry see the edit

Comment: You will have dimension of range equal to $3$ precisely if $T$ is injective, which is equivalent to $\ker T = \{ 0\}$.